# What does timer_getoverrun( ) do?

Tags: c, linux, timer

I am not very clear with this API from it's definition in man page: timer_getoverrun( ).

Can someone help me to explain, with the context of a timer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you create e.g. a 1ms timer, but due to various delays it takes e.g 4.5ms from the signal is generated until it is actually accepted by the application, there *could have been* 3 more signals issued in the meantime (but isn't, since only one signal is pending at a time). `timer_getoverrun()` retrieves the value 3 - the number of signals *not* generated.